# Sumneko lua-language-server failed to load

Tags: neovim, lua, lsp

My OS is openbsd 7.2 with neovim v0.7.2.
I am using the repo at https://github.com/amy-juan-li/nvim-lua.git to configure Neovim.

There is a problem with the `neosolarized.rc.lua` file.

Can anyone see what the invalid character is?

I have included the file below.
Also installing lua-language-server throws this error:

```
error="Could not find which release file to download.
Most likely the current operating system or architecture is not supported (OpenBSD_amd64)."'
```

There's a snippet of the mason log is below.

Is there no way round this ?
If any more file or log Information is needed please let me know.

When I start nvim I get this startup error

```
init.lua is loaded!
Error detected while processing .config/nvim/plugin/lspsaga.rc.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: .config/nvim/plugin/lspsaga.rc.lu
a:4: attempt to call field 'init_lsp_saga' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        .config/nvim/plugin/lspsaga.rc.lua:4: in main chunk
        [mason-lspconfig.nvim] installing sumneko_lua
        Error detected while processing .config/nvim/after/plugin/neosolarized.rc.lua:
        W18: Invalid character in group name
        W18: Invalid character in group name
        W18: Invalid character in group name
        W18: Invalid character in group name
        W18: Invalid character in group name
        W18: Invalid character in group name
        W18: Invalid character in group name
        W18: Invalid character in group name
        W18: Invalid character in group name
        W18: Invalid character in group name
        W18: Invalid character in group name
        W18: Invalid character in group name
        W18: Invalid character in group name
        W18: Invalid character in group name
        W18: Invalid character in group name
        W18: Invalid character in group name
Spawning language server with cmd: `lua-language-server` failed.
The language server is either not installed, missing from PATH, or not executable.
Error detected while processing FileType Autocommands for "*":
Error executing lua callback: .../start/nvim-treesitter/lua/nvim-treesitter/highlight.lua:19:
    attempt to call field 'start' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        .../start/nvim-treesitter/lua/nvim-treesitter/highlight.lua:19: in function 'attach'
        ...er/start/nvim-treesitter/lua/nvim-treesitter/configs.lua:505: in function 'attach_module'
        ...er/start/nvim-treesitter/lua/nvim-treesitter/configs.lua:528: in function 'reattach_module'
        ...er/start/nvim-treesitter/lua/nvim-treesitter/configs.lua:131: in function <
        ...er/start/nvim-treesitter/lua/nvim-treesitter/configs.lua:130>
Press ENTER or type command to continue

--- .config/nvim/plugin/lspsaga.rc.lua' ---
1 local status, saga = pcall(require "lspsaga")
2 if (not status) then return end
3
4 saga.init_lsp_saga {
5   server_filetype_map = {
6     typescript = 'typescript'
7   }
8 }
9
10 local opts = { noremap = true, silent = true }
11 vim.keymap.set('n', '<C-j>', '<Cmd>Lspsaga diagnostic_jump_next<CR>', opts)
12 vim.keymap.set('n', 'K', '<Cmd>Lspsaga hover_doc<CR>', opts)
13 vim.keymap.set('n', 'gd', '<Cmd>Lspsaga lsp_finder<CR>', opts)
14 vim.keymap.set('i', '<C-k>', '<Cmd>Lspsaga signature_help<CR>', opts)
15 vim.keymap.set('n', 'gp', '<Cmd>Lspsaga preview_definition<CR>', opts)
16 vim.keymap.set('n', 'gr', '<Cmd>Lspsaga rename<CR>', opts)

--- .config/nvim/after/plugin/neosolarized.rc.lua ---
local status, n = pcall(require, "neosolarized")
if (not status) then return end

n.setup({
  comment_italics = true,
})

local cb = require('colorbuddy.init')
local Color = cb.Color
local colors = cb.colors
local Group = cb.Group
local groups = cb.groups
local styles = cb.styles

Color.new('black', '#000000')
Group.new('CursorLine', colors.none, colors.base03, styles.NONE, colors.base1)
Group.new('CursorLineNr', colors.yellow, colors.black, styles.NONE, colors.base1)
Group.new('Visual', colors.none, colors.base03, styles.reverse)

local cError = groups.Error.fg
local cInfo = groups.Information.fg
local cWarn = groups.Warning.fg
local cHint = groups.Hint.fg

Group.new("DiagnosticVirtualTextError", cError, cError:dark():dark():dark():dark(), styles.NONE)
Group.new("DiagnosticVirtualTextInfo", cInfo, cInfo:dark():dark():dark(), styles.NONE)
Group.new("DiagnosticVirtualTextWarn", cWarn, cWarn:dark():dark():dark(), styles.NONE)
Group.new("DiagnosticVirtualTextHint", cHint, cHint:dark():dark():dark(), styles.NONE)
Group.new("DiagnosticUnderlineError", colors.none, colors.none, styles.undercurl, cError)
Group.new("DiagnosticUnderlineWarn", colors.none, colors.none, styles.undercurl, cWarn)
Group.new("DiagnosticUnderlineInfo", colors.none, colors.none, styles.undercurl, cInfo)
Group.new("DiagnosticUnderlineHint", colors.none, colors.none, styles.undercurl, cHint)

--- mason.log ---
[INFO  Sat Feb  4 13:47:31 2023] ...acker/start/mason.nvim/lua/mason-core/installer/init.lua:120:
  Executing installer for Package(name=lua-language-server)
[ERROR Sat Feb  4 18:55:38 2023] ...acker/start/mason.nvim/lua/mason-core/installer/init.lua:159:
  Installation failed for Package(name=lua-language-server)
  error="Could not find which release file to download.
  Most likely the current operating system or architecture is not supported (OpenBSD_amd64)."
[INFO  Sat Feb  4 18:55:48 2023] ...acker/start/mason.nvim/lua/mason-core/installer/init.lua:120:
  Executing installer for Package(name=lua-language-server)
[INFO  Sun Feb  5 12:23:11 2023] ...acker/start/mason.nvim/lua/mason-core/installer/init.lua:120:
  Executing installer for Package(name=lua-language-server)
[ERROR Sun Feb  5 12:23:21 2023] ...acker/start/mason.nvim/lua/mason-core/installer/init.lua:159:
  Installation failed for Package(name=lua-language-server)
  error="Could not find which release file to download.
  Most likely the current operating system or architecture is not supported (OpenBSD_amd64)."'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `setup` instead of `init_lsp_saga`.

There was a breaking change.